# passport local for a node.js app with multiple route files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I've  successfully followed [this Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs) and made my Node.js based app.

Now I want to add passport-local support to login for some specific routes. Every tutorial I've found regarding using Passport is for applications with only one route file. but I have my routes in multiple files (in **app.js**) :

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var config = require('./routes/config');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var run = require('./routes/run');
var device = require('./routes/device');
var user = require('./routes/user');
```

For example in **routes/config.js**:

```
router.get('/', server_controller.index);
router.get('/server/create', server_controller.server_create_get);
router.post('/server/create', server_controller.server_create_post);
router.get('/server/:id/delete', server_controller.server_delete_get);
router.post('/server/:id/delete', server_controller.server_delete_post);
```

and in **routes/device.js** we have routes that need login:

```
router.get('/', device_controller.index);
router.get('/change-ip', device_controller.device_edit_ip_get);
router.post('/change-ip', device_controller.device_edit_ip_post);
```

So how should I use passport-local middle-ware in these different route files?

---

**Update**:
in **routes/user.js** I've defined passport local strategy.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var User = require('../models/user');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('login.pug' ,{
      title : "Login Page"
   });
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
   });
});

passport.use('local-login' ,new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField : 'uname',
      passwordField : 'password'
   },
   function (uname , password , done) {
      User.findOne({ uname : uname } , function (err , user) {
        if(err) { return done(err); }
        if(!user) {
           return done(null,false,{});
        }
        if(! User.validPassword(password , user.password)) {
           return done(null , false , {});
        }
        return done(null , user);
     });
   }
));

router.post('/login' , function (req ,res , next) {

   var uname = req.body.uname;
   var password = req.body.password;

   req.checkBody('uname' , 'The user-name field is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('password' , 'The password field is required').notEmpty();

   var errors = req.validationErrors();
   if (errors) {
      res.render('login.pug' , {
         title : 'Login Page',
         errors : errors
      });
      return;
   }
   next();
} , passport.authenticate('local-login' , 
    { failureRedirect: '/user/login' ,
      successRetrunToOrRedirect: '/device'

    }), function (req, res) {
   console.log('login success');
   res.redirect('/device');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then in other route files I've defined isLoggedIn() function and used it, for example in **routes/devics.js**:

```
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, device_controller.index);
router.get('/change-ip', isLoggedIn, device_controller.device_edit_ip_get);
router.post('/change-ip', isLoggedIn, device_controller.device_edit_ip_post);
    router.get('/change-password', isLoggedIn, device_controller.device_change_pw_get);
    router.post('/change-password', isLoggedIn, device_controller.device_change_pw_post);

function isLoggedIn(req , res , next) {
   if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      next();
      return;
   }
   res.redirect('/user/login');
}
```

or in **routes/config.js** again I've defined isLoggedIn() and added where ever I needed authentication:

```
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, server_controller.index);
router.get('/server/create', isLoggedIn, server_controller.server_create_get);
router.post('/server/create', isLoggedIn, server_controller.server_create_post);

function isLoggedIn(req , res , next) {
   if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      next();
      return;
   }
   res.redirect('/user/login');
}
```

It works fine, but I'm sure that it is not the right/best way to do it!

Comment: Just use the same strategy for multiple routes. What's the problem?

Comment: Could you be please more descriptive? how should I use same strategy in different route files? Where do I should define the Strategy?